# WebView below horizontal Scrollview

Tags: android, webview

I want to show the `webView` below the Horizontal Scrollview but if I'm tipping it, the `webView` does not show.
If I dont tipping "layout below horizontal1" then the WebView will shown on Top:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/horizontal1">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

its look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/stMRt.jpg

but i want to show the webView below the TableLayout and not Over :)

Comment: Hi , Could you add expected & output result as images

Comment: are you just looking to enable horizontal scroll view?Please be specific

Comment: i will that the webView will shown below the tableLayout but it will not shown anyway